# How to prevent the Scrollbar out of range?

Tags: delphi, properties, scrollbar, outofrangeexception

I use the code

```
procedure TMyCanvas.RichEditChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  ScrollInfo: TScrollInfo;
begin

  FillChar(ScrollInfo, SizeOF(ScrollInfo), 0);
  ScrollInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ScrollInfo);
  ScrollInfo.fMask := SIF_RANGE or SIF_PAGE or SIF_POS;
  if GetScrollInfo(FRichEdit.Handle, SB_VERT, ScrollInfo) then
  begin
    FVertScroll.Max := ScrollInfo.nMax;
    FVertScroll.Min := ScrollInfo.nMin;
    FVertScroll.PageSize := ScrollInfo.nPage;
    FVertScroll.Position := ScrollInfo.nPos;
  end;
  Invalidate;
end;
```

the problem is that when i add/remove lines it gives me error sometimes when im going to resize the form. it says "scrollbar property out of range"

how can i avoid it?

thanx

Comment: Which line does raise the exception exactly? I'm just guessing that `Min` or `Max` is a property that does some bound checking.

Comment: You could also try `SetPageSize`, `SetParams` to avoid setting individual properties one by one.

Comment: @TOndrej, make that an answer!

Comment: If you're not getting the error when changing the rich edit's contents, I doubt the code in OnChange handler have got anything to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try setting the [`PageSize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/StdCtrls.TScrollBar.PageSize) property, and calling [`SetParams`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/StdCtrls.TScrollBar.SetParams) to avoid setting individual properties one by one.

Comment: +1. The mentioned error only happens when the Min>Max or Max<Min, and that can happen if you set a new Max that's lower then the old Min (the OP's code sets Max first). `SetParams` gets both values at once, so the error shouldn't happen any more.

Comment: @Cosmin - Min>Max and Max<Min are the same things, you probably mean Max<PageSize.

Comment: @Sertac, if you start with `Min = 100` and `Max = 200` you can get `Min>Max` setting `Min=300` and you can get `Max<Min` setting `Max=0`. While mathematically it's the same thing, I wanted to point out the two ways you can get yourself in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error message and found that a change had been made when initialising the scrollbar whereby TScrollbar.Max was being set to 0 when PageSize was 2. Setting PageSize to 0 before Max to 0 fixed the issue.